# richtextbox formatting

Tags: c#

I have a richtextbox control,
        when i load the *.rtf file using a OpenFileDialog to display the contents of that file into richtextbox,it should come in the correct format as in the rtf file(correct format means spaces,font size,word wraping,color etc..)
i just want to know how to format the richtextbox..?
                        (or)
is there any other way to do it..?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link could help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx

```
public void CreateMyRichTextBox()
{
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
    richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


    richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf");
    richTextBox1.Find("Text", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);

    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

    richTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\\MyDocument.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

    this.Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to format ALL text in RTB :)
Try to use format like bolds, italics, etc in various fragments of text :)
Examples like the above are used to circumvent the troublesome issues and hide author's ignorance (in this case - ignorance of MSDN article author).